# Replace only background color of PNG

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
# Generate test image.
convert -size 100x60 xc:blue -fill blue -stroke black -draw "circle 50,30 55,55" in.png

# Make background transparent.
convert in.png -fill none -draw 'matte 0,0 floodfill' -flop  -draw 'matte 0,0 floodfill' -flop out.png
# Replace transparent background with green.
mogrify -background green -flatten out.png

# The wrong way.
convert in.png -transparent blue oops.png
mogrify -background green -flatten oops.png
```

It is based on this snippet: https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/558-how-to-remove-a-background-with-imagemagick

Starting with this:

[image: Black circle filled with blue, blue background]

I want to get this:

[image: Black circle filled with blue, green background]

Not this:

[image: Black circle filled with green, green background]

Can I achieve this with a single `convert` command instead of a `convert` followed by a `mogrify`?

I am using ImageMagick 6.8.9-9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you are seeking a *"floodfill"*, like this:

```
convert in.png -fill green  -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png
```

[image]

That will look at the top-left pixel (`0,0`) and fill all similarly coloured pixels **which are connected to it** with green. If your background has slight variations in it, e.g. it's a JPEG, add some *fuzz factor*

```
convert in.jpg -fuzz 25% ...
```

---

Note that if your circle had touched the top and bottom edges, it would prevent the fill from flooding around to the right side of the diagram. So, let's say you had created your circle like this:

```
convert -size 100x60 xc:blue -fill blue -stroke black -draw "circle 50,30 50,0" in.png
```

[image]

And then you run the above command, you will get:

[image]

If that happens, you can add a single pixel wide border all the way around for the colour to *"flow"* through first, then flood-fill, and finally remove it later:

```
convert in.png -bordercolor blue -border 1 -fill green  -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -shave 1x1 result.png
```

Comment: To fill with transparency instead of a color, use: `convert in.png -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png`.