# Imagemagick: how do I an irregular region of color

Tags: imagemagick

When I have an image like the following, is it possible to convert the outer (!) orange to transparency? It's like trim, but I need to remove the outer region of orange color and convert that color to transparent. However, the inner orange must not be touched.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928633/replace-only-background-color-of-png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try flood filling the outer color.

```
convert Zx5HL.png -fill transparent -fuzz 50% -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' output.png
```

[image: output.png]

... but that'll introduce clipping artifacts.